# Controller RESTful methods in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

when i executing    php artisan make:controller Test  command  in laravel 5 
i am getting below blueprint

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Test extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

But Documentation said we should get skeleton with RESTful methods

```
 class Test extends BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

So what is wrong in my case . how to get what exactly RESTful Resource Controllers should be  ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add `--resource` option at the end of this command to generate a RESTful controller. Following the [official laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers), your command should be like this:

```
php artisan make:controller Test --resource
```